# Python subprocess python script

Tags: python, command

I want to create python console that can run not only regular commands but also python and other commands. For example how can I run this script and provide input with subprocess?

```
print("Welcome to simple program !")
data = input("Enter something: ")
print(data)
```

Comment: define "regular commands", do you mean shell commands?

Comment: shell commands are done with os.system() if youre willing to open another window or subprocess otherwise

Comment: By regular commands I mean commands like ls, cd, pwd, ... But I want to be able to open "python" command. (I want to be able to have an interpreter so I can for example test some python module like in regular terminal or cmd)

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Try this http://xon.sh/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import subprocess

print("Welcome to simple program !")
cmd= input("Enter something: ")
subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)
```

> **Security Considerations**
> Unlike some other popen functions, this implementation will never implicitly call a > system shell. This means that all characters, including shell metacharacters, can safely be passed to child processes. If the shell is invoked explicitly, via shell=True, it is the application’s responsibility to ensure that all whitespace and metacharacters are quoted appropriately to avoid shell injection vulnerabilities.
> When using shell=True, the shlex.quote() function can be used to properly escape whitespace and shell metacharacters in strings that are going to be used to construct shell commands.
> [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations)